# Calculate the slope of a line on an auto-scaled chart?

Tags: transformational-geometry

Let say, I have a line with two points `A=(1, 10.09)` and `B=(3, 10.42)` on an auto-scaled chart like this.

[image]

I would like to calculate the slope of this line. Can I transform the y-coordinates (or the real slope) into a new system, provided that the inteval, start and end points of the chart are known? Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, this is mistagged as transformational-geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Currently, your slope is:
$$
\frac{y_{B}-y_{A}}{x_{B}-x_{A}}=\frac{10.42-10.09}{3-1}=\frac{0.33}{2}=0.165,
$$
and therefore the equation of the line is
$$
y=0.165x+b.
$$
The line must go through the point $x=1$ and $y=10.09$, so that
$$
10.09=0.165\cdot1+b
$$
and
$$
b=10.09-0.165=9.925.
$$
Hence, the equation of the line is
$$
y=0.165x+9.925.
$$
However, as you hinted at, this equation is not particularly nice.
Note that 
$$
0.165=\frac{33}{200}
$$
and
$$
9.925=\frac{397}{40}.
$$
The least common multiple of $200$ and $40$ is $200$ (see http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/lcm.php if you do not know what a least common multiple is). Multiplying
the original equation by $200$, we get
$$
200y=33x+1985.
$$
This equation looks better. If we define a new variable, $\hat{y}=200y$,
we get the equation
$$
\hat{y}=33x+1985.
$$
We can verify this equation works as intended. Take $x=1$, then
$$
\hat{y}=2018
$$
and
$$
y=\frac{\hat{y}}{200}=\frac{2018}{200}=10.09.
$$